# HotSpot адаптивная оптимизация и JIT компиляция

Tags: java, hotspot, jvm

Ребята. Помогите ссылками. Где можно почитать про то как устроена технология *адаптивной оптимизации* и *JIT* в HotSpot JVM. есть ли какие то книги? любая инфа которая даст понимание как там все это устроено.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Тут по-английски http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/hotspotP.html  
Тут по-русски [habrahabr.ru/post/122061/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122061/)